# Docker doesn't copy assets folder

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I don't have a .dockerignore file but Docker doesn't copy assets folder to the images when building.

project:

- assets

  - models

    - v1
- src
- venv
- Dockerfile

App.py :

```
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf                                   
                                  [...]
    with open('../assets/model/v1/model_architecture_V1.json', 'r') as f:
        model_json = f.read()

    model.load_weights("../assets/model/v1/model_weight_V1.h5")

                                  [...]

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=4000, debug=True)
```

Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3

    WORKDIR /app

    COPY requirements.txt ./
    RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

    COPY . .

    CMD ["python3","src/app.py"]
```

When I run the project image,Python throws me this error:

[image]

- When I run the app without Docker there is no problem.

Comment: What if you're specific, `COPY ./assets /assets` etc.?

Comment: As  explained in the Docker documentation "The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.". Is your assets directory containing files or is it empty ?

Comment: When you run it locally, are you in the `src` directory or the directory above it?  I expect `../assets` paths to be interpreted relative to the current directory and not necessarily the script directory.

Comment: Can you replace that image with the actual text of the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CMD ["python3","src/app.py"]
```

Observe this statement, you are running the `app.py` script outside the `src` folder but not inside the `src` folder.
So `open()` function takes the path either the absolute one or the relative one. When it comes to the relative path you need to provide the path from where you are running the python script `app.py` as you are running outside of the `src` folder, therefore, your path should also be given the same way. So it will be `assests/models/v1/model_architecture_V1.json`

There is nothing to do with the docker file or it's the position here. You should understand how the copy and movement to the directories happening in your container and then also understand the nature of python, you need to provide the relative path on the basis of where you are running the script but not with respect to the position of the python script `app.py`.

Answer (score 1):

When you test locally set `../assets/..` is valid. But during the Docker build both Dockerfile and assets folders are located at the same level. So, you have to change the file path as `assets/..`. To handle this efficiently in Python check `os.path.join`.

```
    Step 3/6 : COPY . .
    ---> 49a93d46bdde
    Step 4/6 : RUN ls -lah
     ---> Running in f57d57b59dce
    total 24K
    drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K May 29 21:21 .
    drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K May 29 21:21 ..
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  168 May 29 21:19 Dockerfile
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K May 29 20:53 assests
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May 29 21:21 src
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May 29 20:54 venv

    ---

    with open('assests/models/v1/model_architecture_V1.json', 'r') as f:
       model_json = f.read()
```

Sample output

```
docker run harik8/app:latest                  
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
                "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
                        "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                                        "SortAs": "SGML",
                                        "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                                        "Acronym": "SGML",
                                        "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                                        "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                                                "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                                        "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```